# Why does mysql reverse the order of rows when selecting multiple tables depending on their size?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not interested in "Join" concept yet. I'm trying to figure what really happens underneath when using:

`select * from table1, table2`.

I've built two tables, `numbers` and `letters`:

[image: Output of selecting numbers and letters rows]

When using `select * from numbers, letters`, the output is:

[image: Select every row from both tables, numbers first]

I jumped to the conclusion that SQL matches every row from first table to the second table, by pointing some kind of iterator [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwUB9.png) from last row to first row on the first table, then first row to last row on second table [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwUB9.png), resetting [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwUB9.png)s position back to the end of first table each time [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrhyQ.png) reaches a new position.

The same happens when inverting letters first, number last:

[image: Select every row from both tables, letters first]

However I believe I'm wrong, as when I inserted more values to `numbers`, the follow happened:
[image]

In that try, even though the query selects `numbers, letters`, numbers got "fixed" and letters got "reverse iterated", not the other way around.

Being honest, what I was really expecting first place when selecting `numbers, letters` was something like:

```
1 a
1 b 
1 c
2 a
2 b
2 c
3 a
3 b 
3 c
```

What *really* happens underneath when selecting multiple values? I found many answers concerning how to use joins to achieve x result, but not so much content talking about what SQL is generating with the original query first place.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: "The order could even change between two identical queries just because of data that has changed between those queries. a "where" clause may be satisfied with an index scan in one query, but later inserts could make that condition less selective, and the planner could decide to perform a subsequent query using a table scan."

Comment: That indeed does! I was not aware of the existence of that command, either that the order of the output of a query was not reliable. Thank you very much @Renat!